# How to store click position without global variables? Matplotlib/Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to stop a random plotting with just clicking the screen, but the examples I've seen use global variables and I don't want to use them. So what can I do?

This is my code so far. The function onclick is an idea I took from Matplotlib documentation, but they used it to print information on the console and I want to store it in a variable and then return it (for example in one variable called "get_mouse" and then break the while-cicle).

Pd: I know there're some crimes, sorry I'm a beginner...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def onclick(event):
    if event.dblclick :
        print('help me')

plt.ion()

B=np.random.random((1,5))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2,2),ylim=(-2,2))
line, = ax.plot([],[],'bo', ms=4)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)


while True:
    S=np.random.random((1,5))
    line.set_data(B+S,B-S)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    if get_mouse == True:
        break
```

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a class and have `get_mouse` be a member of that class, then you would be able to modify it from inside `onclick`

Comment: Thank you! I did it in this way: `class clk1: get_mouse=False def __init__(self): pass def onclick(self,event): if event.dblclick: self.get_mouse=True def click(self): return self.get_mouse` Is there a better way or is it okay like that?

Comment: That’s how I would do it

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you!